# If it's “double” why is it singular?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, countable-nouns

1. *A double number* is two identical numbers, e.g. 007 (*double O seven*)
2. *A double chin* is someone who appears to have two chins
3. *A double feature* is a program showing two feature-length movies
4. *A double D* is a bra with two DD cups
5. *A double standard* is a rule or principle which is unfairly applied in different **ways** to different people or groups ([EOD](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/double_standard))
6. *A double yolk* is an egg with two yolks

All the nouns listed above are countable but stay singular. On the other hand, if we substituted the word *double* with *two* the noun is pluralized e.g.

> *I cracked open an egg and found two yolks*

**Why don't we use the plural noun in these cases?**

- I cracked open an egg and found double yolks (NO)
- I cracked open an egg and found **a** double yolk (YES)

[image]

---

There appears to be an exception to the rule and it is ***double doors***. According to [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20double%20door%2C%20the%20double%20doors&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20double%20door%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20double%20doors%3B%2Cc0), today the plural form compared to its singular counterpart is used 80 times more frequently.
<sub>(Hopefully, I didn't mess up the maths, but if I did please correct me)</sub>

[image]

Answer (score 4):

According to Collins dictionary, [double](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/double) as defined in definition 2:

> Adj. You use double before a singular noun to refer to two things of the same type that occur together, or that are connected in some way.
>
> E.g *...an extremely nasty double murder*.

Answer (score 2):

Because the subject of **is** in your examples is the *name* for something. That thing is understood as a single compound entity or thing.

> I bought tickets for the double-header but *it* got rained out.

Comment: But the *double yolks* are inside the egg (?!) And in the sentences the subject is "I" and "a double yolk" is the object.

Comment: I am talking about your list of sentences at the top.  We don't say *She are a triple threat.*  The reference is to a monad of three. *She is a triple threat. A triple threat is what she is.*

Comment: +1 for "monad" I had to look it up, I haven't seen that word in years

Comment: Monads are crepuscular. But you've probably seen plenty of dyads and triads, tetrads and pentads in broad daylight.

Answer (score 0):

"Double" is an adjective describing the noun. The noun determines whether it is singular or plural.

From your examples:

- double **zero** or double **D**- singular
- double **chin**  - singular
- double **feature** - singular
- double **standard** singular
- double **doors** - plural

"Double-yolk" is a bit of a special case, and is complicated. It's an adjective describing an egg (a "double-yolk egg"), which doesn't actually say the noun. Think of the sentence, "The best of us are happy." you can see that "best" is not normally a plural noun; so where does that "are" come from? "Best" is an *ellipsis of the noun phrase*, which just means that the actual noun is left out. You can read that as "The best [people] of us are happy," and it will make more sense (or any other noun that matches "us"). In the same way, read "double-yolk" as "double-yolk [egg]", and it will make more sense.

It may be worth noting that many of these also work fine as plural, but have a slightly different meaning:

- You might have a "double chin" which means your face is shaped a certain way. If so, your "double chins" are the actual face bumps.
- "Double D" means "DD", most commonly understood as a bra size. "Double D's" are the objects that fit inside such a bra.
- "Double door" tends to indicate the portal size, while "double doors" refers to the actual swinging piece.

Comment: Where I come from, a 'double chin' is usually a sign of obesity, rather than heredity.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey yes? I’m not sure where I implied otherwise.